# ckEditor - mouseup event not firing after setData

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, dom-events

I have a ckEditor loaded through Javascript, then on the `instanceReady` event I add another event for `mouseup`... this works well and dandy until I use the `setText` property (I used both the jQuery way and the Javascript way). After that is set, the `mouseup` event no longer triggers. Not even after I set the event handler again.

Relevant code:

```
var elem = CKEDITOR.instances[eID];
elem.document.on("mouseup",function(){
            QuickHandler(elem);
        });



function QuickHandler(who)
{

    $("#"+who.name).val(who.getData() +    QuickTextSelected.QuickTextData);
       $("input[type='text'],textarea, .cke_contents").css({border: "Solid 1px rgb(155,181,234)"}).unbind("click");
    

}
```

This is the jQuery plugin version, but it works the same way with the internal Javascript ckeditor object map. (Rather it doesn't work).

Does `setData` or `setText` clear all event handlers?

Comment: Would be lovely if someone could help look for this, as i have the exact same issue, but with keyup and paste event... both events don't trigger anymore after we submit the form and clear the texteditor's content trough setData(''); after that none of the events seem to fire anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that by using setData CKEditor infact replaces the document element rendering your events invalid, see [#6633](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6633)